# How do I translate the output of a filter in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, translation

I have some template code that looks like:

```
<input type='submit' value='{{ need.satisfied|yesno:"Resend this document now,Send this document now" }}' />
```

I'd like to be able to translate it but that appears to be difficult to accomplish.

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3804 mentions

```
{{ _("Some String") }}
```

which appears to work for literal strings, but when used like

```
{{ _(Variable) }}
```

gives the error

```
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: '_'
```

So, how do you do it?

Oh yea, I tried doing:

```
'{% if blah %}{% trans "Resend..." %}{% else %}{% trans "Send..." %}{% endif %}'
```

which works, but look so ugly I don't want to.  Surely with Django there is some more elegant way to do this.....

Seems like a |trans filter would be in order, but that was shot down as a non-issue with http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3804

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Judging by the example in the docs, it might be possible to do it like this:

```
<input type='submit' value='{{ need.satisfied|yesno:_("Resend this document now,Send this document now") }}' />
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using, [blocktrans](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#blocktrans-template-tag)

```
{% blocktrans %}
    string to translate with {{ vars }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Part of the problem comes from the need to be essentially {% spaceless %} because it is in the value attribute, the spaces are significant (and the newlines).

The {% spaceless %} tag won't work because it just removes spaces between html tags, and therefore has not effect here.

WolpH nailed this one